# i need to count data where two columns could be duplicates or more

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
name              --              country              --              order
john Abraham      --               USA                 --              burgar
john Abraham      --               USA                 --              cake
john Abraham      --               USA                 --              sugar
CR RONALDO        --               PORT                --              burgar
MESSI GAR         --               ARG                 --              burgar
john Abraham      --               FRA                 --              burgar
```

i need the result to be

```
Count
 4
```

the result is 4 because "john Abraham from USA has 3 results but i counted as 1"

Comment: The count of instances of that name is indeed 4, but your logic for getting the result makes no sense. Buy what's wrong with a simple SELECT COUNT query? What have you tried?

Comment: @ADyson everything make sense.....what am trying to do is to get the total count of users and the only way to know that user is the same is to check the name and country

Comment: if i count with SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM table the results will be "6"

Comment: and if i use DISTINCT the result will be "3"

Comment: Use Group By name

Comment: same wont give the sum result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count distinct is not limited to 1 column

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t (name varchar(3), country varchar(3));

insert into t values
('aaa','usa'),('aaa','usa'),('aaa','usa'),
('bbb','fra'),('ccc','gdr'),
('aaa','uk');

select count(distinct name,country) from t ;

+------------------------------+
| count(distinct name,country) |
+------------------------------+
|                            4 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/count-distinct/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

Comment: At least not if using Mariadb. (ANSI/ISO SQL standard has 1 column only.)

Comment: @jarth concatenating columns so there is only one column before applying distinct also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS count  FROM TABLE WHERE name = 'whatever name'
```